# is there a GRAMPS descendant or family report that includes photos

Tags: software-recommendations, gramps

I have tried to find a report in GRAMPS that has the features that I require.  I want a family or descendant report that ***includes primary person photos***.  There is one other requirement: It needs to be able to display in a way that is useable when there are large number of children (up to twenty).  *DescendantLines* is one report that has almost all the requirements, but it only displays horizontally, making it impossible to post on a webpage or view without problems because the output is so wide (it would work if it had a vertical option because I only need 2 or 3 generations).

If there is no report like this, could you suggest an alternative free option? (I don't want to purchase software just for one report)

Answer (score 1):

There is a detailed descendent report including images which you can install.
See https://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php/Detailed_Descendant_Report_With_All_Images